# Vagrant hosting service

Tags: web-server, hosting, cloud, cloud-hosting, vagrant

On a small project we use Vagrant for development environments.

Given the simplicity of the setup, we are considering using it for production since it's a small project with low traffic.

I know I can take a classic server, fire Vagrant and re-route th 80 port to the virtual machine, but I wonder if a more appropriate solution exist. Like a hosting where you could deploy a Vagrant machine without having a "host" to maintain: only the virtual machine would be accessible.

Comment: PHP + Apache to serve it. But the whole point of Vagrant (that I love) is that the hosting don't care about what's in there. I can install whatever I want. I also have NodeJS project that I'd love to be able to deploy like that. That's so easy once everything is set up. I hate doing sysadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Vagrant 2 you can deploy to cloud hosting providers like AWS.  You shouldn't need to modify your Vagrantfile too much to achieve this.

Comment: Great I just found it in "Providers" in the docs, thank you